# Unable to get the mesh from collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, raycasting

in Unity, how does one get a sharedMesh from a mesh collider which has multiple meshes?

i have a model to which i've added multiple mesh colliders.  imagine a tank with several weak points that are targetable.

when i raycast to these weak points, i do get hit info but when i try to get the name of the specific mesh that was hit, i can't:

```
mesh_name = hit_info.collider.sharedMesh.name;
```

gives me this compiler error:

*'UnityEngine.Collider' does not contain a definition for 'sharedMesh' and no extension method 'sharedMesh' accepting a first argument of type 'UnityEngine.Collider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

this is even though sharedMesh exists and i can even see it show the correct mesh in the Watch window!

if i iterate through all the mesh colliders within this model and compare it with the one hit, i can find it:

```
MeshCollider[] meshes = hit_info.collider.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshCollider>();
for ( int i = 0; i < meshes.Length; i++ )
{
    if ( meshes[ i ] == last_hit_info.collider )
    {
        // found the mesh
        mesh_name = meshes[ i ].sharedMesh.name;
        break;
    }
}
```

but surely there's a better way.

thanks.

Comment: Use GetComponent<MeshFilter>.